# Golang Highcharts dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, go, highcharts

I am currently learning golang and a bit of webstuff on the way. So excuse my maybe not so smart question

My problem is that I want to provide a Highchart with dynamic Data. I looked up the documentation and the example but cannot get it to work.

The Highchart example:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


    <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
    <script>
    var chart; // global

    /**
     * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
     */
    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                    shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                // add the point
                chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: [1]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- 3. Add the container -->
    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

My Server should Provide a json encoding string as requested.

```
func main(){
http.HandleFunc("/",foo)
http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
func foo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
numbers := []int{14,5}
js, err := json.Marshal(numbers)
if err != nil {
http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
return
}
fmt.Println("Received Request")
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/json")
  w.Write(js)
}
```

I can see that the highchart makes a request. My guess it that the ajax call does not understand my json?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Edit: Do I habe to do a success message  as a return too?

Comment: You might be getting an error from your ajax call. Add an error call back to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (thx to @jmaloney 's hint)

```
{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
ajax.html:28 parsererror: Error: jQuery110109016359453089535_1446814074235 was not called
```

A simple

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

on my go-Server solves it :)